# Filtering on data with a cast string->float type

Tags: python, pandas

a few issues here but i think the code is relatively straight forward.

the code is as follows:

```
        import pandas as pd

        def establishAdjustmentFactor(df):
            df['adjFactor']=df['Adj Close']/df['Close'];
            df['chgFactor']=df['adjFactor']/df['adjFactor'].shift(1);
            return df;

        def yahooFinanceAccessor(ticker,year_,month_,day_):
            import datetime
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            month = str(int(now.strftime("%m"))-1)
            day = str(int(now.strftime("%d"))+1)
            year  = str(int(now.strftime("%Y")))
            data = pd.read_csv('/Users/myDir/Downloads/' + ticker + '.csv');

            data['Date']=float(str(data['Date']).replace('-',''));
            data.set_index('Date')
            data=data.sort(['Date'],ascending=[1]);
            return data

        def calculateLongReturn(df):
            df['Ret']=df['Adj Close'].pct_change();
            return df;

        argStartYear = '2014';
        argStartMonth = '01';
        argStartDay='01';

        argEndYear = '2014';
        argEndMonth = '04';
        argEndDay = '30';

        #read data
        underlying = yahooFinanceAccessor("IBM,"1900","01","01");
        #Get one day return
        underlying = establishAdjustmentFactor(calculateLongReturn(underlying));

        #filter here
        underlying = underlying[(underlying['Date'] > long(argStartYear + argStartMonth +  argStartDay)) & underlying['Date']<long(argEndYear+argEndMonth+argEndDay)];
```

Where this will evolve to a function and argStart(End) would be arguments to the function.

The idea is that there will be some parent function call that will keep a global dataframe of the entire price history of an underlying, and later calls will access that dataframe and filter on dates needed to see if there were splits.

Now, when I read the data and attempt to convert in the `read_csv` call i get the following error:

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
              File "/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
                execfile(filename, namespace)
              File "/Users/myDir/Documents/PythonProjects/dailyOptionValuation.py", line 70, in <module>
                underlying = yahooFinanceAccessor("SVXY","1900","01","01");
              File "/Users/myDir/Documents/PythonProjects/dailyOptionValuation.py", line 37, in yahooFinanceAccessor
                data['Date']=float(str(data['Date']).replace('-',''));
            ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0     20140424
            1     20140423
            2     20140422
            3     20140421
            4     20140417
            5     20140416
            6     20140415
            7     20140414
            8     20140411
            9     20140410
            10    20140409
            11    20140408
            12    20140407
```

Any input as to why would be extremely helpful!

Comment: IIUC, `data["Date"]` is the entire Date column, which you're converting to a string, removing `-` from, and then trying to convert to a float.  Why *should* that work?

Comment: So, pretty new to this (obviously). i think generally speaking my overall goal is quite obvious, while your comment is pointless. thanks for that.

Comment: If you're new enough that the difference between an element of a column and a column is still fuzzy to you, then I was going to write a different kind of answer than if you'd immediately said "oops, you're right!"  You can look at my [previous pandas answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a487339%20[pandas]) to judge for yourself whether it's likely I would have done so.

Comment: Well that's not the fuzzy part at all. Actually str(data['Date']).replace('-','') runs just fine. It appears the behavior though is not quite as expected and would need to be applied to the column via a function. This alone would have been a more productive answer to begin with. Thank you for the injection of personality.

Comment: snarkiness aside, I think your problem is that you're trying to convert the column into a string and then you're trying to work with the string; if you put together a self-contained example that includes the data and all the relevant code (with proper indentation etc so we can run it ourselves), you might have more luck getting an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears as if I have found the issue after poking around a little bit, and changing the way I was thinking about the problem.

Any input on if there is a more efficient way to do this would be great.

```
    def operateOverSetToCreateEasyKey(df):
        for i in df.index:
            df.ix[i,'fmtDate']=int(str(df.ix[i]['Date']).replace('-',''));
        return df;
```